# Combiner passé composé avec imparfait

Tags: passé-composé, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

Y a t'il une explication sur le fait de combiner un passé composé avec un imparfait dans cette phrase :
"J’ai toujours su que je voulais être pompier."

(je ne vois dans aucun cours la possibilité de combiner le passé composé avec l'imparfait. Pourtant, dans mon exemple ci-dessus, cela semble vraiment naturel.)

Est-ce que les phrases suivantes sont correctes ?

- "Je sus toujours que je voulus être pompier."
- "Je sus toujours que je voulais être pompier."
- "Je savais toujours que je voulais être pompier."
- "J'avais toujours su que je voulais être pompier."
- "J’ai toujours su que je voulais être pompier."
- "J’ai toujours su que je voudrais être pompier."

Laquelle est la meilleure, pour un narrateur qui raconte le passé ? (il est désormais pompier)
Pourquoi ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Je sus toujours que je voulus être pompier.

Correction après réponse de [user jlliagre](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/52182/17649) : cette combinaison n'est pas utilisable, la concordance des temps n'est pas établie. contexte improbable ; au cours d'une période du passé je n'ai jamais oublié qu'à un moment antérieur à cette période j'avais dans l'idée de devenir pompier. On dirait plus normalement « Je sus toujours que j'avais voulu être pompier."

> Je sus toujours que je voulais être pompier.

Correct ; Au cours d'une période passée j'étais resté conscient d'une volonté de devenir pompier.

> Je savais toujours que je voulais être pompier.

Correct, mais contexte particulier;

- Mes désirs étaient multiples et j'aurais aimé être dans les postes, et à un certain moment je pensais à la marine ; finalement je ne savais plus très bien si je voulais vraiment une chose ou l'autre ; cependant, Je savais toujours que je voulais être pompier.

Valeur de « [toujours](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/toujours) » B. − [Marque la prise en charge d'un argument, sans doute faible, mais considéré comme acquis et qui restera valable quoi qu'il arrive]

> J'avais toujours su que je voulais être pompier.

Correct ; pendant toute une période donnée jusqu'à un certain moment dans le passé j'étais conscient de ma volonté de devenir pompier.

> J’ai toujours su que je voulais être pompier.

Correct ; pendant toute une période donnée jusqu'au moment où finalement je suis devenu pompier  j'étais conscient de ma volonté de devenir pompier.

ou

pendant toute une période donnée jusqu'à aujourd'hui j'ai été conscient de ma volonté de devenir pompier (et je ne le suis toujours pas  **ou** je viens de le devenir  **ou** je suis sur le point de le devenir).

> J’ai toujours su que je voudrais être pompier.

Correct ; une nuance supplémentaire est ici exprimée par le conditionnel : « mais il n'est pas certain que je puisse l'être ».

Comme il vient de devenir pompier, c'est la cinquième qui convient.

Comment: Si au final, il n'était pas devenu pompier, est-ce que la phrase 5 serait correcte ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Oui, et cette possibilité est même comprise dans ma réponse ( « et je ne le suis toujours pas » ) ; il pourrait même ne plus avoir cette ambition ; il faudrait ajouter que dans ce dernier cas la phrase peut impliquer toutes sortes d'insinuations plus ou moins ironiques qui découlent du contexte (construction type), mais cela constitue une petite étude en soi.

Comment: merci beaucoup pour votre aide

Comment: Tu fais comme tu veux, mais si tu pouvais arrêter de m'appeler "user jlliagre" et dire simplement "jlliagre" ou "@jlliagre" comme tout le monde, ce serait sympa...

Comment: @jlliagre Va pour @ jlliagre ; je devrais pouvoir me rappeler du traitement spécial.

Comment: @LPH : j'aimerais vous contacter en privé : y a t'il un moyen ? Contactez moi à mathieu.krisztian@gmail.com si c'est possible, merci.

Comment: La seule façon serait par l'intermédiaire d'un site sérieux  d'échanges écrits qui permette de préserver l'anonymité;  je préfère ne pas risquer que mon adresse courriel soit distribuée ou qu'elle soit connue de personnes  qui me sont hostiles (et il y en a sur le présent site mais pas seulement). Il est possible d'utiliser la page discussion (le chat : chez Causette); certains s'en servent pour toutes sortes de communications: opinions sur des films américains, discussions politiques, cuisine, nouvelles, etc.

Comment: @LPH Il ne s'agit pas d'un traitement spécial pour moi, c'est au contraire l'usage attendu pour tous. Le traitement spécial, c'est celui d'utiliser un mot anglais dans des échanges en français là où personne d'autre le fait.

Comment: @jlliagre Je l'aurais déjà utilisé mais ce n'est pas bien  logique ; « le commentaire de   àXXXX » ? Ça ne me plait pas. Personne d'autre le fait, soit, c'est vrai, mais je ne me soucie pas trop de faire comme les autres. Personne ne sortait avec des pantalons déchirés il y a un certain nombre d'années et maintenant c'est normal. Vous préférez « utilisateur » ?

Comment: Si, bien que ce soit une convention depuis des années dans tous les programmes de ce style, c'est le @ qui te gène, ne met pas de @ et utilise simplement le nom/pseudonyme, comme c'est l'usage depuis toujours en français. *Après réponse de jlliagre* est très clair, pas besoin de l'alourdir avec *Après réponse de l'utilisateur jlliagre*.

Comment: @jlliagre Et quand l'utilisateur utilise l'alias « Victor Hugo », j'écris « après réponse de Victor Hugo » ? Non, c'est trop bête.

Comment: Puisque tu mets un lien vers la réponse, personne ne va penser que le "vrai" Victor Hugo a répondu à une question sur FSE, si tant est qu'il y ait des utilisateurs pour penser que c'est possible.

Comment: @LPH : excusez moi , je ne comprends pas comment techniquement vous contacter quand vous dites "utiliser la page discussion (le chat : chez Causette)". Pouvez-vous me contacter sur la page en question ?

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian Tout utilisateur qui a acquis 20 points peut adresser un commentaire à n'importe quel autre utilisateur au moyen de la page discussion (invariablement appelé le « chat » (anglais, prononcé «  tchat » t final) ou aussi « Chez Causette » quand il s'agit du FSE. il est possible d'échanger des commentaires indéfiniment de cette façon, et il n'est pas nécessaire que ce soit à propos d'une question formelle. Pour accéder la page discussion, il suffit d'accéder à l'écran le fond de n'importe quelle page de question réponse et de cliquer « chat ». Cela produit le chat ; (1/2)

Comment: @MathieuKrisztian  au bas de l'écran il y a un champ à texte. il suffit d'entrer l'arobase suivi du nom de l'utilisateur (sans séparation, comme pour le commentaires dans les pages question-réponse). Ensuite il n'y a plus qu'à taper son texte. Les problèmes sont les suivant : 1/ après un court instant il n'est pas possible d'éliminer un commentaire (il faut demander à un modérateur de le faire), 3/ Il y a très peu de temps pour faire une correction, 3/ la quantité de texte par envoi est limité (plus petite que pour les commentaires. Je vous envoie du texte maintenant. (2/2)

Comment: À l'écran le fond ?? Tu ne peux pas interpeller quelqu'un à partir de Chez Cosette si il n'y a jamais été. @MathieuKrisztian Le chat est ici : https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1098/chez-cosette

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî « accéder à l'écran X » : mettre X sur l'écran.

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî Mettre le lien c'est bien mais savoir où se trouve une command pour utiliser le lien automatiquement ce n'est pas mal non plus. Il y a ce lien au fond de la page, c'est bien pour l'utiliser. Ensuite il y en a un autre en haut, mais caché. Il y a une loi qui interdit le bas de la page ?

Comment: @mastödantirâfamî On peut être plus précis, évidemment, mais au cas où ça n'aura pas été suffisant on est toujours là pour ajouter le détail ; il suffit de demander.

Answer (score 4):

1. ❌  *Je sus toujours que je voulus être pompier*: agrammatical.
   → *Je sus toujours vouloir être pompier*. (mais très peu idiomatique)
2. ❓   *Je sus toujours que je voulais être pompier*: non-idiomatique.
3. ✅  *Je savais toujours que je voulais être pompier*: je ne l'avais pas oublié à l'époque.
4. ✅  *J'avais toujours su que je voulais être pompier*: le discours se situe dans le passé.
5. ✅  *J’ai toujours su que je voulais être pompier*: le discours se situe au présent.
6. ❓  *J’ai toujours su que je voudrais être pompier*: (concordance des temps discutable car *voudrais* est un présent).
   → ❌ *J'ai toujours su que je **veux** être pompier*. (clairement incorrect)
   → ✅ *Je voudrais être pompier, je l'ai toujours su*.
   → ✅ *Je veux être pompier, je l'ai toujours su*.
   → ✅ *J'ai toujours su que **j'allais vouloir** être pompier*.
   → ✅ *J'ai toujours su que **je voulais** être pompier*. (5.)

La première phrase est bien agrammaticale selon *[Passé simple et spécificité](https://www.persee.fr/doc/equiv_0751-9532_1989_num_17_1_1112)*, 1989, par Suzanne Hanon (docteure en linguistique).

C'est une construction similaire au cas 9a qui est clairement rejeté.

[image]

Comment: Vous auriez une référence pour « 1. » et « 6. » ?

Comment: @LPH Le bon sens.

Comment: Il me semble que toutes les phrases sont grammaticales.

Comment: On trouve, par exemple, de nombreux cas de « a », « ai », et « avons » avec « toujours cru qu'il serait ». https://www.google.com/search?q=%22toujours%20cru%20qu%27il%20serait%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_fr

Comment: @Mathieu Pourquoi pas mais bonne chance quand même avec *Je sus toujours que je voulus[...]* À supposer que la phrase soit grammaticale, ce dont je doute, elle n'a pour moi aucune chance de passer la barrière d'un correcteur professionnel.

Comment: @lliagre : certes, la phrase est bancale mais "correcte grammaticalement".

Comment: Il semble bien que non.